# Reading content from multiple files in C

Tags: c, file

Example:

**Three files**

hi.txt

**Inside of txt:** "May we be"

again.txt

**Inside of txt:** "The ones who once"

final.txt

**Inside of txt:** "knew C"

***And then, another file called "order"***

order.txt

**Inside of txt:**

"**hi.txt;6**"

"**again.txt;7**"

"**final.txt;3**"

What I want: read the first file name, open it, list the content, wait 6 seconds, read the second name, open it, list the content, wait 7 seconds, read the third name, open it, list the content, wait 3 seconds.

If I do it without opening the content (you'll see a second while on my code) and list the names, it works, yet for some reason it doesn't when it's about the content.

```
orderFile = fopen("order.txt","r");

    while(fscanf(orderFile,"%49[^;];%d",fileName,&seconds) == 2)
    {
        contentFile = fopen(fileName,"r");

        while(fscanf(contentFile,"%[^\t]",textContent) == 1)
        {
            printf("%s\n", textContent);
        }

        sleep(seconds);

        fclose(contentFile);
    }

fclose(orderFile);
```

Output:

> May we be
>
> (Waits 7 seconds)
>
> Program closes with "RUN SUCCESSFUL"

***EDIT@***

It works now, as you guys said, this was the problem:

**Old:**

```
while(fscanf(orderFile,"%49[^;];%d",fileName,&seconds) == 2)
```

**New:**

```
while(fscanf(orderFile," %49[^;];%d",fileName,&seconds) == 2)
```

I'm having a "hard" time to completely understand it, what does the space does? doesn't accept enters? spaces? What exactly is it?

Comment: `"%49[^;];%d"` --> `"%49[^;];%d%*c"` or `" %49[^;];%d"` @chux have pointed out about the newline in the previous question.

Comment: The space skips all `\n`(newlines) and spaces before scanning data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `fscanf` for that

```
int
main()
{
    FILE *orderFile = fopen("order.txt", "r");
    if (orderFile != NULL)
    {
        int  seconds;
        char line[128];

        /* 
         * fgets, read sizeof line characters or unitl '\n' is encountered
         * this will read one line if it has less than sizeof line characters
         */
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, orderFile) != NULL)
        {
            /* 
             * size_t is usually unsigned long int, and is a type used 
             * by some standard functions.
             */
            size_t fileSize;
            char  *fileContent;
            FILE  *contentFile;     
            char   fileName[50];
            /* parse the readline with scanf, extract fileName and seconds */
            if (sscanf(line, "%49[^;];%d", fileName, &seconds) != 2)
                continue;
            /* try opening the file */
            contentFile = fopen(fileName,"r");
            if (contentFile == NULL)
                continue;
            /* seek to the end of the file */
            fseek(contentFile, 0, SEEK_END);
            /* 
             * get current position in the stream, 
             * it's the file size, since we are at the end of it 
             */
            fileSize = ftell(contentFile);
            /* seek back to the begining of the stream */
            rewind(contentFile);
            /* 
             * request space in memory to store the file's content
             * if the file turns out to be too large, this call will
             * fail, and you will need a different approach.
             * 
             * Like reading smaller portions of the file in a loop.
             */
            fileContent = malloc(1 + fileSize);
            /* check if the system gave us space */
            if (fileContent != NULL)
            {
                size_t readSize;
                /* read the whole content from the file */
                readSize = fread(fileContent, 1, fileSize, contentFile);
                /* add a null terminator to the string */
                fileContent[readSize] = '\0';
                /* show the contents */
                printf("%s\n", fileContent);
                /* release the memory back to the system */
                free(fileContent);
            }
            sleep(seconds);
            fclose(contentFile);
        }
        fclose(orderFile);  
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Everything is barely explained in the code, read the manuals if you need more information.

Comment: I'm just a begginer so I have some questions. Why is that *c on the fscanf? What is size_t? What is malloc(1 + fileSize);? What is free(fileContent)? The same as rewind? But I'll try something out based on this

Comment: @Ran I updated the code, hope it's more helpful now.

Comment: I've made mine with the change of a space only and it worked, thank you though, I've learned some new things with this one. :)